# Characterization of Prüfer domains via valuation rings and modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I am learning valuation rings from Matsumura’s *Commutative Ring Theory* book.
There is an exercise that characterizes Prüfer domains among integral domains.
Let $A$ be an integral domain. The exercise asks us to prove the equivalence of two conditions on $A$:

> (1) The localization $A_m$ at any maximal ideal $m$ of $A$ is a valuation ring.

> (2) Every $A$-module is flat if and only if it is torsion-free.

I managed to show (1) implies (2).
But for (2) implying (1), I am stuck. I have tried to use the fact that the localization $A_m$ at any maximal ideal $m$ of $A$ is a flat $A$-module, and by (2), it is thus torsion-free. And I tried to use the fact that the field of fractions of $A$ is the same as that of each $A_m$ to derive (1).
But I failed.
Could somebody help me with the implication (2) implies (1)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376759/588038

Comment: @cqfd Thank you very much for your information and help.